# Stop http service, yum still work CentOS7

Tags: centos, yum, repository, http

Can anyone explain me why yum still working when I stop http service.

If I'm not wrong, yum repository use port 80 and 443 so stop http service on the machine should technicly stop possibility to install packages ?

Comment: Are you stopping the `http` service on the machine hosting the repository you’re using?

Comment: You might want to read up what the difference between a http _server_ and a http _client_ is, and what exactly the `http` service does.

Comment: I'm stopping http service on my local machine.  
where I am wrong ?

Comment: Also, take a look at how your yum repositories are defined in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Any repositories defined with `http://` URLs would certainly require a functional HTTP server on the host that holds the repository; but a local repository can also be defined using a `file://` URL, which tells `yum` just to go and read the repository files directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have stopped the **service** which responds to http requests, but your PC can still ask others for files using a client. The **yum** app is a client, which, in part, asks the web to send things so they may be installed.